# Launcher App Slow

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.2-jelly-bean, launcher, motorola-droid-4

I installed an unofficial build of Cyanogenmod 10.1 [from here](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/droid-4-roms/231899-unofficial-cm10-1-jb-4-2-1-rom-development-01-29-updates.html) on my Droid 4 and the launcher app runs really slow. When I scroll through the screens or scroll in the app drawer it lags very bad. Should I do a factory reset on my phone?

Comment: What do you mean by unofficial? Did you install the nightly version?

Comment: Did you do a wipe (dalvik cache and/or cache/data) when installing CM?

Comment: @GreenGuy Unofficial means it was made by someone else, not the cyanogenmod team.

Comment: @Izzy Yes I cleared both caches and data.

Comment: That's strange then. Maybe simply try a different launcher then -- and be it just to check if it makes a difference? You might even "fall in love" with the replacement, and forget about your "original problem" that way :)